# Access to global JS variables without owning the page

Tags: javascript, communication

overflow community,

I've read several posts trying to solve the problem, but they dont answer my question.

**Is there any legal way to find out what events (?) another site sends?** 
I dont ask because of illigal buissness and i am ready to find out more myself as soon as i know what i realy have to look for  in terms of topic and methods.

In particular its about advertising and finding out if someone registered on another via a referal link. Like a sign that is sent as soon as the    registration (on the other site which is not mine) is completed.
I want to find this out during the visit of the client on my site.

I just need to know if such a thing is legally possible and what JS topics i should give a go to find out more.

I hope my post is comprehensible enough. :)

*edit: It's not about global variables.*

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense; your use of the term "global variable" seems to refer to something other than what the term actually means.  I think, however, that the basic answer to your question is **no**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your browser's developer tools to see what's happening behind your back while you're visiting a web page (I recommend [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) in Firefox). Alternatively, you may use a network spoofer like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) to capture the traffic from the browser and analyze it in any way.

It's all up to you to find the information you think is relevant inside it in URLs, in request headers and bodies, etc. In your case, this would include script generated content and referal codes that may help keeping track of a user's browsing history across domains.

You don't really need Javascript knowledge to do this, but you need some basics about networking protocols.

This is probably as illegal as using a text editor, but just ask your lawyer if you're unsure :D